# XNA - detecting collision with array objects

Tags: c#, xna

So I am making a Space Invaders clone in XNA. I need to do the collision detection logic. My invaders are held within an array. Each invader has it's own rectangle bounding box. So if my ship touches one invader it should loose halth or something like this. Here is my invader class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PackedVector;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Design;

namespace SpaceInvaders
{
    public class botInvaders
    {
        public botInvaders()
        {

        }

        public static Texture2D botInvaderTex;
        public static Rectangle botInvaderHitBox;
        public static Vector2 botInvaderOrigin;
        public int botInvaderCurrentFrame = 1, botInvaderFrameWidth = 52, botInvaderFrameHeight = 90, invaderRows = 3, invaderCollumns = 10; // invaderRows = 5 // For 50 invaders
        float botInvadersTimer = 0f, botInvadersInterval = 100;
        public static Rectangle[,] botInvadersRect;
        String botInvadersDirection = "RIGHT";
        public static Color invadersColor = Color.White;
        SoundEffect invaderTeletransportation;
        SoundEffectInstance invaderTeletransportationInstance;

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            botInvaderTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\gameGraphics\\gameSprites\\botInvaders\\normalInvaders\\invaderShip1");
            invaderTeletransportation = Content.Load<SoundEffect>(".\\gameSounds\\teletransportation");
            invaderTeletransportationInstance = invaderTeletransportation.CreateInstance();
            invaderTeletransportationInstance.IsLooped = false;
            botInvadersRect = new Rectangle[invaderRows, invaderCollumns];
            for (int r = 0; r < invaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < invaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    botInvadersRect[r, c].Width = botInvaderFrameWidth;
                    botInvadersRect[r, c].Height = botInvaderTex.Height;
                    botInvadersRect[r, c].X = 70 * c;
                    botInvadersRect[r, c].Y = (70 * r) + 22;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            botInvaderHitBox = new Rectangle(botInvaderCurrentFrame * botInvaderFrameWidth, 0, botInvaderFrameWidth, botInvaderFrameHeight);
            botInvaderOrigin = new Vector2(botInvaderHitBox.X / 2, botInvaderHitBox.Y / 2);

            botInvadersTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

            if (botInvadersTimer > botInvadersInterval)
            {
                botInvaderCurrentFrame++;
                botInvadersTimer = 0f;
            }

            if (botInvaderCurrentFrame == 2)
            {
                botInvaderCurrentFrame = 0;
            }

            if (Game1.gameStart == 2)
            {
                invaderTeletransportationInstance.Play();
            }

            botInvaderHitBox = new Rectangle(botInvaderCurrentFrame * botInvaderFrameWidth, 0, botInvaderFrameWidth, botInvaderFrameHeight);
            botInvaderOrigin = new Vector2(botInvaderHitBox.Width / 2, botInvaderHitBox.Height / 2);
        }

        public void Draw(Texture2D invadersTex, Rectangle[,] invadersDestinationRect, Nullable<Rectangle> invadersSourceRect, Color invadersColor, float invadersRotation, Vector2 invadersOrigin, SpriteEffects invadersEffects, float invadersScale, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < invaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < invaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(botInvaderTex, botInvadersRect[r, c], botInvaderHitBox, Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ship class is basically the same thing without the array (it is only one):
So it also has a `playerShipHitBox` too.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Update()` method, you can just do a simple rectangle intersects check:

```
for (int r = 0; r < invaderRows; r++)
    for (int c = 0; c < invaderColumns; c++)
        if (botInvadersRect[r, c].Intersects(playerShipHitBox))
            // BAM! Collision!
```

Comment: @Charlie Could be a problem with your rectangles (size, location) then.